# limit geolocation API calls in Excel with VBA.

Tags: excel, vba, api, recursion, geolocation

I am using google geolocations API to get the coordinates of an address in excel. My address that im looking up wont change that often so I don't want to keep calling the API once I have the lat,lng data every time I recalculate the workbook. I am using the lat, lng to get weather data that will recalculate more frequently.
I have tried to use a recursive function to call the cell where the function is written to see if I have already made the API call or not(I don't want to keep updating a cell with the same information).
I had wanted to use the isblank function in vba but it was not working for me to check if the cell had any data all ready. I think my code makes sense and should work. Is there a better way to do this and do I make any sense at all?

```
Function TT(Address As String, self As Integer) As Variant
Debug.Print "TT is open__________________________________"
Debug.Print Now()   
Dim key          As Integer
Dim latlng          As String
key = self

Debug.Print Address
Debug.Print self
'this will be set by the self value and should update???
If key = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "****recursive call****"
    key = 1
    Call TT(Address, 1)
End If

latlng = GetCoordinates(Address)
Debug.Print latlng
Debug.Print "Excting function"
TT = latlng
```

End Function

Comment: I might be under-thinking this, but why not just use a hidden sheet to track the known address <---> lat\long combos?

Comment: Hidden sheet is a sensible way to go for tracking, or even a write to database, but it does sound like there may be instances where you do want to make another call with the same co-ordinates, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @QHarr yes I do want to make other calls after I get the data. I am using the dark sky api to get weather info and I will also be mapping the points. Say I have 10 address I want to get weather information for I only want to call the api 10 times and store those coordinates. Once I have the coordinates I will have the weather api update off of them, 2 or 3 times having the weather api call 20 or 30 times. The if I add another location to my list I only want one api call will be made because the other 10 will already have been called and have data.

Comment: Sounds like you have a workeable solution in the answer below then :-)

Comment: I haven't been able to try that code yet but I think it will work fine. But for the sake of asking questions could you do this without using any more memory, or adding anything to a list? You know for science!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is basically to keep track of what `Address`'s you have processed, and only call `GetCoordinates` for ones you haven't already processed.  The key is where to store the `Address`'s you've already processed.

Possibilities include

- On a (hidden) sheet <sup><sub>(nod to Cominterns comment)</sub></sup>
- Store in a Static data structure, eg Dictionary
- Store in a (hidden) Name
- and many others

Here's a **Static Dictionary** version.  (Late Bound, with optional Early Bound version commented)

```
Function TT(Address As String, Optional Reset As Boolean = False) As String
    Static LLs As Object 'Dictionary
    Dim latlng As String

    If LLs Is Nothing Then Set LLs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")  ' Set LLs = New Dictionary
    If Reset Then LLs.RemoveAll
    If LLs.Exists(Address) Then
        TT = LLs(Address)
    Else
        latlng = GetCoordinates(Address)
        LLs.Add Address, latlng
        TT = latlng
    End If
End Function
```